# Matplotlib Basemap Coastal Coordinates

Tags: python, basemap, matplotlib-basemap

Is there a way to query basemap to extract all coastal coordinates? Say user provides lat/lng and the function returns true/false if the coordinates are within 1km from the coast?

Links are more than welcome.